# Xcode 4 - Lost Certificates and Provisioning Profiles, how do I recover

Tags: iphone, xcode4, sdk

I recently had a crash on my Macbook Pro. The disc became corrupted and unbootable. A new disc was installed together with Snow Leopard and Xcode 4. I also recovered 4 (published) applications and one in development from a backup. All are safe and well and working except, I don't have the development certificate and provisioning profiles. I have attached the iPhone to my machine and the Team Provisioning Profile, and a specific profile for the app currently under development seems to have been recovered from the device but I'm uncertain how to recover the Certificate, or whether to create a new one (the published - distributed - apps profiles have expired so I'm not concerned about them) an. I currently get a 'Valid signing identity not found' message for each profile.  I need some help/advice. There is nothing left of the old disc to recover from and I'm afraid I didn't export any Provisioning Profiles.

Comment: Just go to the Developer Portal and download the provisioning profile again. That seems to be the easiest solution

Comment: Next time make a full time machine backup. It should back up everything, including profiles.

Answer (score 2):

As Owl said, go the Developer Portal at developer.apple.com and click iOS Provisioning Portal. Then, from the left pane, you can redownload your certificates and provisioning profiles. Install your certificates through Keychain Access, and drag your profiles into Xcode (they should appear in Organizer).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Apple Developer Portal and download your certificate again.